# If my old desktop PC has a pentium D CPU in it now, can I be pretty certain a core 2 duo E7500 will work in it?

Tags: cpu, upgrade, intel-core2

If my old desktop PC has a Pentium D CPU in it now, can a be pretty certain a core 2 duo E7500 will work in it?

It used to be same socket (both are socket 775 I'm told) means they're compatible; I'm hoping I can just pop one out and the newer one in and it'll work (although the newer CPU may be limited a bit by the Motherboard's FSB speed).

I don't have a manual for the motherboard so I can't check that or Google it to check compatibility.

**Update:** As suggested, I used CPU-Z to get the MB model number and looked up the CPU compatibility chart on the manufacturer's website. Problem solved. No luck for upgrading, though - the CPU I already have is the max for this mainboard.

Comment: OK, I'll get CPU-Z and check the manufacturers website. Now... I have 3 great answers (so far), but I'm not sure which one to pick as the most correct and informative answer (for others who came across this question). John T says different power requirements are the problem, but Wil says different chipsets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not saying no, but I wouldn't bet on it.

The CPU limitation is mainly down to the chipset and not the actual socket it fits in to.

Your best bet is to use a tool such as [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/cpuz.php) which should be able to give you your motherboard details, then you can confirm on their website what your board supports.

Also, You may need to do a BIOS update to support it, but the manual/documentation should be able to tell you.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't count on it.  I had an older machine with a Pentium 4.  I was building a new machine and got a Pentium Dual Core (not even a core 2 duo), and I tried it out in the old machine.  It didn't POST.

Comment: I like this one because it's based on actual real-life experience.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't be certain without the model. First generation Socket 775 Pentium 4,D, and XE motherboards may be incompatible due to different power requirements. Some motherboards may list [compatibility with Pentium Dual Core as well as Core 2 Duo](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813135230), and some may only list [Core 2 Duo compatibility](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813136052) or vice-versa. Check with CPU-Z as already mentioned to be sure on your motherboard before making the purchase.